# Use custom system service in app (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-source

First of all, thank you for your help.

Here is my problem.

1. I have made a custom system service (it does connect through the binder, and hooks into the system server, then into the HAL, etc). One of the main commands is isBacklightOn(). I also ran the make update-api to include it in my ROM build.
2. I am now ready to test the functionality using an app. I am using the following code:

```js
import android.os.BacklightManager; //My service manager name

...
BacklightManager bm = (BacklightManager) getSystemService(BACKLIGHT_SERVICE);
...

if(!bm.isBacklightOn()) {
  //Turn it on.
} else {
  //Other Things...
}
```

My problem occurs because Android Studio will not build the application due to not knowing what the BacklightManager is. How can I build this application to test my code? (import something into Android Manager, force a build ignoring errors, etc.)

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, do you mind telling me how you solved it?

Comment: Tom, I have been unable to get this solution to work perfectly well. One possible solution is to build the app in Android Studio, and then sign it with the android system key, making it essentially a system app (also the same as building it in with AOSP). This makes it unnecesary for the app to use the SDK to access any of the services in Android. Another (the "right" solution) is to look at the information given by Dave Smith on SDK Add-Ons. This is possibly the better way to do it, but I have not looked heavily at it.

Comment: I imported the AIDL of my service into my Project, i can now compile it. 
But when I call 
    customService = (MyCustomService) getSystemService("MyCustomservice") 

customService stays null.

I can see my service running with service list in the shell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the solution is to build a custom SDK within the AOSP build environment. And then import that into Android Studio